# Laravel get POSTed data using request

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel how do I get the request body? I am trying $request->get(‘data’) but I get a null result. I am doing a POST request to a store function in my controller but I am unable to get the POSTed data.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $test = $request->get('data');

}
```

Comment: Maybe the manual can help: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Laravel, you can fetch the request input data by using $request->all(). This will then return the input data as an array. You can find more in the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input).

Comment: Awesome, glad to help

Answer (score 11):

Retrieving All Input Data

```
$data = $request->all();
```

Retrieving An Input Value

```
$name = $request->input('name');
```

Retrieving An Input Value with default value

```
$name = $request->input('name', 'Sally');
```

For details read Laravel document here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

Answer (score 4):

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input), there are many ways to to access a input data.

Generally, you use dynamic properties `$request->data` and to check if a post item exists you can use `has()`.

**Reading Material**

[HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests)

Comment: Did not know about has()!

Answer (score 3):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('store')}}" >
   <input type="text" name="data"  />
   <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

in your web.php

```
Route::post('/store','YourController@store')->name('store');
```

in your controller :

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $data=$request->input('data');
}
```